# How can I downcast an instance generated by static method?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a C# program that includes the following :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Child childInstance = Child.ParseFromA(@"path/to/Afile") as Child;
    }
}

class Parent{
    int property;

    public static Parent ParseFromA(string filename)
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        // parse file and set property here...
        return parent;
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public void SomeAdditionalFunction() { }
}
```

When running this code, `childInstance` becomes `null`.

I tried below assignment with explicit cast, but ended with an exception :
`Child childInstance = (Child)Child.ParseFromA(@"path/to/Afile");`

Since I want to parse some types of files into `Parent` and `Child` instance, I want to keep the design that generates instances by static methods.

How should I get a proper `childInstance`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot downcast it. Once an object has been created as a `Parent`, it will *always* be a `Parent`. It's like trying to downcast a `new object()` to a `string`: That just won't work - which character sequence should this string represent?

Thus, your only solution is to *create the correct object*. The only option I see in your case is to make your static method generic:

```
public static T ParseFromA<T>(string filename) where T : Parent, new()
{
    T t = new T();
    // parse file and set property here...
    return t;
}
```

Usage:

```
Child childInstance = Parent.ParseFromA<Child>(@"path/to/Afile");
```

The generic constraint `T : Parent` ensures that `T` is a subtype of `Parent`, and `new()` ensures that `T` has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is exactly what I wanted to do !  
I Applied it and perfectly worked.

Comment: Just a small thing about your example: it is completely sane to try downcast an `Animal` into a `Cat`: you receive a `Cat` if it was a `Cat` and `null` if it wasn't (that's what author does). The problem here is that if you create an `Animal`, you create an abstract animal, that cannot be a cat. It is a model that just doesn't have a kind. If you talk about a man, you don't mean `John`, - you mean some abstract man. I'm pretty sure that was the intention, but I thought it is a bit unclear from your example.

Comment: @Archeg: You are, of course, completely right. I've modified my example and decided to go with some framework classes.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using static methods and do not want to use reflection or generics, then you can also consider using `new` keyword:

```
class Parent
{
    public static Parent ParseFromA(string filename)
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.Parse(filename);
        return parent;
    }

    protected virtual void Parse(string fileName)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public new static Child ParseFromA(string filename)
    {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.Parse(filename);
        return parent;
    }

    protected override void Parse(string fileName)
    {
        base.Parse(fileName);
        SomeAdditionalFunction();
    }
}
```

Personally I would just use instance methods.

```
var child = new Child(...);
child.Parse(...);
```

An extra line of code is a small price to pay for cleaner code, IMHO. `static` keyword does not play well with inheritance, as you can see. You can also always wrap instance method into extension method, if you want a one-liner after all:

```
public static class ParentEx
{
    public static T ParseFile<T>(this T source, string fileName) : where T : Parent
    {
        source.Parse(fileName);
        return source;
    }
}
```

and then

```
var child = new Child().ParseFile(fileName);
```

Comment: Or use virtual on base class, override on child class

Comment: @Mafii  for instance methods, yes. You can't override static methods though.

Answer (score 2):

If your static method does not know what type to create, you need to pass it. For example by using generics:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var childInstance = Parent.ParseAs<Child>(@"path/to/Afile");

      childInstance.SomeAdditionalFunction();
    }
  }

  class Parent
  {
    int property;

    public static T ParseAs<T>(string filename) where T : Parent, new()
    {
      var parent = new T();

      // parse file and set property here...
      parent.property = 42;

      return parent;
    }
  }

  class Child : Parent
  {
    public void SomeAdditionalFunction() { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only cast to a parent class, not to a child class. The compiler could not safely assume that the object has been constructed properly, has all necessary properties to be safely accessed as a child object.

Either use a generic method as mentioned above by Heinzi or use a parametrized constructor and an instanced parsing method within parent and child class.

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent() { }
    public Parent(string fileName) 
    {
         Parse(fileName);
    }

    private void Parse(string fileName)
    {
        // Do your parsing stuff here.
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public Child() { }
    public Child(string fileName) : base(fileName)
    {
         // Parsing is done already done within the constructor of Parent, which is called by base(fileName)
         // All you need to do here is initialize the rest of your child object.
    }
}
```